# Single Responsibility Principle- when to stop extracting code into separate classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm reading "Rails AntiPatterns" at the moment, and one of the first patterns mentioned is the Single Responsibility Principle.  At this point I've encountered SRP enough times to realize that it's a fundamental concept for beginners like me to understand, which is why it's so frustrating that it's not clicking yet.

The book gives an example of an Order class:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.find_purchase
    #...
    end

    def self.find_waiting_For_review
    #...
    end

    def self.find_waiting_for_sign_off
    #...
    end

    def self.advanced_search(fields, option = {})
    #...
    end

    def self.simple_search
    #...
    end

    def self.advanced_search
    #...
    end

    def to_xml
    #...
    end

    def to_json
    #...
    end

    def to_csv
    #...
    end

    def to_pdf
    #...
    end

end
```

To illustrate SRP, the book recommends extracting out the 4 instance methods into a separate OrderConverter class.  This makes sense to me.  But at the same time, this OrderConverter class could still have multiple reasons to change:

- If the application no longer requires one of the 4 formats mentioned,
  the corresponding method would have to be deleted.
- If the application
  needed to convert to other formats, more methods would need to be
  implemented.
- If the method used to convert Order instances to different formats is 
  changed (assuming they all use the same method with a different parameter 
  which corresponds to the format required).

Wouldn't it be even more "correct" to separate each of these methods into a separate converter class (i.e. PdfConverter, CsvConverter, XmlConverter, etc.)?  That way, the only reason for each converter class to change would be if the conversion method itself changed.  If a new format was needed, a new class could be created.  And if an old format is no longer needed, the class could simply be deleted.  And should the original Order model really be responsible for finding instances of itself?  Couldn't you separate the 'find' methods into a separate 'OrderFinder' class?

I've read the SRP chapter of Sandi Metz's "Practical Object-Oriented Design In Ruby", and she recommends the following test to see if a class has a single responsibility:

> How can you determine if the Gear class contains behavior that belongs somewhere
>       else?  One way is to pretend that it's sentient and to interrogate it.  If you 
>       rephrase every one of its methods as a question, asking the question out to make 
>       sense.  For example, "Please Mr. Gear, what is your ratio?" seems perfectly 
>       reasonable, while "Please Mr. Gear, what are your gear_inches?" is on shaky 
>       ground, and "Please Mr. Gear, what is your tire(size)?" is just downright 
>       ridiculous.

But taken to an extreme, if a model has more than one attribute (i.e. a car has a # of doors and a color) with corresponding attr_accessors, isn't this already a violation of SRP?  Doesn't each new attribute add another possible reason for the class to change?  Clearly the answer is not to separate each of these attributes into separate classes.  So then where does one draw the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write about the `OrderConverter` class but you didn't show the source of that class. I assume that this class contains methods to_xml, to_json, to_csv and to_pdf.

> Wouldn't it be even more "correct" to separate each of these methods into a separate converter class (i.e. PdfConverter, CsvConverter, XmlConverter, etc.)?

Yes, it's propably a good idea to separate these methods to converter classes: each converter class will be *responsible* for only one format (one responsibility).

> ... if a model has more than one attribute (i.e. a car has a # of doors and a color) with corresponding attr_accessors, isn't this already a violation of SRP?

Nope, these attributes (like color, no of doors, ...) are not a set of responsibilities! The responsibility of `Car` class is describing a Car (holding an information about a car). Each instance of car will describe one car. If a car for example is a model class (let's say you want to store a cars in DB and one instance of car is one row in DB) then you have to change the Car class if you want to change a *way of describing a car* in your system.

But if a car will have defined for example a producer, and a producer will be described by name and address then I would extract the details of producer to other classes because this is a responsibility of *describing a producer of a car* and not a Car itself.

One more thing. The SRP is not a pattern. This is a Principle (first in SOLID). This term was introduced by Robert Cecil Martin. Here http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to decide that extracting colour and number of doors into seperate classes is too far, which I'd disagree with. Indeed, if car is a very simple car class, maybe it is somewhat over the top. However, there are only a certain number of valid colours, only certain numbers of doors are valid. What if I want to be able to identify my car colour by any of a series of aliases?

CarColor seems like a perfectly valid class to me. It can store all the logic of what is and is not a valid color, provide aliases etc.

Consider an example I've dealt with recently concerning names in a series of places in different forms:

Database 1: Joan Smith

Right, I'll take the name, stick it in a String and put it in my person. No point making a fuss and wrapping one thing in it's own class.

Database 2: Smith, Joan

Ok, so I'll override the setter, check for this format and flip it if it's right.

Database 3: person: { title: Mrs, first: Joan, last: Smith }

Right, we'll just stick the title on the beginning, concatenate the last 2 together and then glue the whole thing into our damned string.

Database 4: foreign name that doesn't follow your structure and the whole concept of first, middle, last takes on a completely different meaning.

...turns out names are complicated.

This can all be nicely avoided by taking your supposedly simple structures and delegating to another class to handle what a name means, when are two names the same, how do we print them etc.

Prematurely wrapping all singleton values in their own classes can be somewhat overkill - but I've found that a bias towards wrapping when in doubt tends to serve me well later even if it feels silly at the time, especially when the value permeates through the rest of the code and so changing it later affects everything.